# Strange behavior in Polymer data-binding to an attribute

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

Using Polymer 1.0 I'm trying to bind to an attribute of a custom element, and just display it.

The custom element is in fact an `<iron-input>` list, that has an add and a delete button. I'd like to reflect any change in that list to the host. It also has a `minItemSize` attribute meaning it has at least this many elements. So I added a check to the observer, adding extra elements in case it goes under this number.

But when I bind to the attribute that holds the list, things get out of sync, and I can delete all of the inputs from the ui.

I have two `<dyn-inputlist>` elements. In one of them I don't bind to the `data`
attribute, in the other I do.

The first one behaves as expected: adds and removes on the button click.

The other doesn't work, because you can remove all input boxes. Even though the data itself is updated, and filled with extra items, for some reason the UI doesn't reflect this. (Checking the data property of the element does show that it has the correct number of items)

I also expect that if I set `data={{myData}}` on both `dyn-inputlist` element, they always display the same thing. But pressing add/remove buttons randomly on either component gets them out of sync.

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/dyn-inputlist.html"/>
</head>
<body>

<template is="dom-bind">
    <dyn-inputlist min-item-size="4"></dyn-inputlist>
    <div>{{mydata}}</div>
    <dyn-inputlist min-item-size="4" data="{{mydata}}"></dyn-inputlist>
</template>

</body>
</html>
```

`dyn-inputlist.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-input/iron-input.html">

<dom-module id="dyn-inputlist">
    <template>
        <button on-click="removeItem">x</button>
        <button on-click="addItem">+</button>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <div>
                <span>{{index}}</span>
                <input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{item.content}}">
            </div>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'dyn-inputlist',
            properties: {
                minItemSize: {
                    type: Number,
                    notify: true,
                    value: 1
                },
                data: {
                    type: Array,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    notify: true,
                    value: function () {
                        return []
                    }
                }
            },

            observers: ['_dataChanged(data.*)'],

            addItem: function (e) {
                this.unshift('data', {content: ""});
                this.reflectPropertyToAttribute('data')
            },

            removeItem: function (e) {
                this.shift('data');
                this.reflectPropertyToAttribute('data')
            },

            _dataChanged: function (e) {
                if (this.data != null) {
                    while (this.data.length < this.minItemSize) {
                        this.push('data', {content: ""})
                    }
                } else {
                    this.data = [{content: ""}];
                }
                this.reflectPropertyToAttribute('data');
            }

        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

EDIT:
This is the live code: http://jsbin.com/poquke/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played around a bit with your code and I noticed that it will work if you wrap the code in your changed handler in an async function. This fixed both issues that you described.

```
_dataChanged: function (e) {
    this.async(function(){
        if (this.data != null) {

            while (this.data.length < this.minItemSize) {
                this.push('data', {content: ""})
            }
        } else {
            this.data = [{content: ""}];
        }
    });
}
```

I don't have a perfect explanation for this behaviour. I assume it is related somehow to the way Polymer handles the observation for changes. Each time you push to the data array in the changed handler, this in fact changes data and should in turn trigger the handler again.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Looks like it's also needed when I have a callback inside a callback.

Comment: This update method causes a lot of unneeded recursion due to the updates. Calling reflectPropertyToAttribute is unnecessary since the property as this set property behavior already set to true.  Also, the bind of the function is unnecessary since calling async automatically binds the function to the context of the caller (this)

Answer (score 0):

No async is required if you simplify.

Here is the simplified code, this removes the repeated calls to _dataChanged when you push the minimum values, and allows polymer's built-in eventing system to take care of updating and notifying the other elements. A function: _createNewItem() is for creating an object. This simplifies where item object creation is handled.

http://jsbin.com/vemita/6/edit?html,output

The link and URL references have changed from the sample code in the question above to conform to the polymer element and demo page standards to be used with polyserve.

I've commented on your original code for why each line should or shouldn't be there. this includes the reason for the changes to _dataChanged

http://jsbin.com/ponafoxade/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. And looking at the code I'm not sure how it's supposed to work. I thought `ready` is called only once. How is it supposed to run that code and add the extra placeholder elements in response to the remove button? Also, how does the data get updated in the host if we don't have the `reflectToAttribute`?

Comment: No need to reflect to attribute if you are using data binding and notify.

Comment: Ready only needs to be called once. The remove method handles removing the element from the array, and when this happens the repeat template reacts to the change. Same with the add button. You can see a demo of your code working here: http://jsbin.com/vemita/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I see. But now a crucial part of the code (the check for minimum number of items) is in the `ready` function which only runs once. I want that at any time there should be no less than 4 items is the list. I also want it to be enclosed in it's own element, because I will use it in another one. So I don't want the dom-repeat outside of the component.. it complicates the client code.

Comment: I really don't understand the difficulty here. If you want the minimum number to stay at "minItemSize" then check for it within the removeItem function. The dom-repeat doesn't need to be outside of the element. If you expand upon your problem maybe I can help. But there is nothing that you've described that cannot be resolved by checking the minItemSize before actually shifting the first item off of the list. The dom repeat in the test is only for showing the results of the item. It's totally not necessary.

Comment: Sorry about the dom-repeat it is indeed not necessary. But the function needs to be in `_dataChanged`, in case someone from outside modifies the data (like in the case I mentioned, when two of these `dyn-inputlist`s are bound together.

Comment: Ok. So show me a code example. I would be happy to explain how the works without the internal observer. The template does the observation, and notifies all interested parties. If you change the data array without using the polymer accessors, no matter what polymer observer you have, the elements will not be updated since you did not use the polymer accessors to make the change. Here is a working code sample, with the observer to listen to external changes via polymer methods:  http://jsbin.com/vemita/2/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Thanks, your example kind of works, but not really. The behavior differs a bit, but that I could fix. What I couldn't fix is that your code references libs from rawgit.com while I'm using Polymer 1.0.0 (using bower) and your code doesn't work with that. [This git repo](https://bitbucket.org/gjuhasz86/dyn-inputlist-demo/overview) contains all the combination I tried. Tags v5 and v6 work as expected. Regarding `reflectToAttribute`, as you pointed out it's not needed. But it actually doesn't change anything. Listening only on `data.length` is also a good point. Thanks for that.

Comment: Could you add code as an example of why it doesn't work? I'm curious. The only time there would be an issue is if you modify the code directly and try and call notifyPath. But then that's an issue with polymer itself. As such you should always use the polymer accessors to modify the data array.

Comment: Try the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/gjuhasz86/dyn-inputlist-demo/src/4fe4e7b9ed83582a4249d7d3764d783bc0436cb6/?at=v7) or [here](https://bitbucket.org/gjuhasz86/dyn-inputlist-demo/src/629f559c2e2539551db253ab46dcc322ef10d889/?at=v8), neither of them works. Weirdly, the same code works if the code references `<script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>` and `<link rel="import" href="https://rawgit.com/Polymer/polymer/master/polymer.html">` but it doesn't work if it points to libs downloaded using bower. The repo has `bower.json` too

Comment: I updated my code. My code used the latest version. The update uses 1.0.0. There is a bug in polymer < v1.0.8 that requires the mydata array to be set on the app dom-bind template before the others are initialized. Adding app.mydata=[] just after the assignment to the app variable should fix it.  http://jsbin.com/vemita/edit?html,output

Comment: Got it. So I needed to change 3 things in my code: (1) Upgrade to Polymer >1.0.8 or use the workaround to initialize mydata first. (2) Change the observer parameter from `data.*` to `data.length`. (3) Add a call to the `_dataChanged` function after removed an element from the list. **These are the points I must change, the others are optional**, but still useful. like to remove `reflectToAttribute`. Please add this to your answer to make it clear what the actual fix is, then I'll accept it. You can also include [the live code with the minimal fixes](http://jsbin.com/poquke/3/edit?html,output)

Comment: I'm still puzzled about a couple of things, though. Like I would assume that `data.*` listens for changes on length too. Or that calling `this.shift('data')` would result in a call to `_dataChanged` too

Comment: data.* listens to all changes on any element of the data object. And that is not what you want in this instance. You only want to ensure that the data length is at least min-data length. Calling this.shift('data') alters data. This calling _dataChanged, even when within the event handler itself. I will update my answer to reflect these changes.